# Synchronizing ListWheelScrollView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

When I scroll through one List Wheel Scroll View, the other list either lags or does not scroll smoothly.
https://pub.dev/packages/linked_scroll_controller allows to sync lists but does not support FixedExtendScrollPhysics.

Output : -

[image: https://media.giphy.com/media/tpUIY3KgavxZoOVmvP/giphy.gif]

https://pub.dev/packages/linked_scroll_controller  works perfectly if we are using ScrollPhysics but throws an error when used with a widget that uses FixedExtendScrollPhysics. I want both the list to move Synchronizing that is if I move green list I want red list to move simultaneously and vice versa

Code :

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'List',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const List(),
    );
  }
}

class List extends StatefulWidget {
  const List({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ListState createState() => _ListState();
}

class _ListState extends State<List> {
  final scrollController = FixedExtentScrollController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("List"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 600,
              width: 300,
              child: ListWheelScrollView(
                  itemExtent: 100,
                  physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                  onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      scrollController.animateToItem(value,
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                          curve: Curves.easeInOut);
                    });
                  },
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) ...[
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                      )
                    ]
                  ]),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 600,
              width: 300,
              child: ListWheelScrollView(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                  itemExtent: 100,
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) ...[
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                      )
                    ]
                  ]),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: The main reason your scroll isn't smooth because you using `setState();`
using setState will render all page-widgets that are inside the associated class if the page contains animation, the animation will laggy. Try to remove setState() or separate ListWheelScrollView() into a different class or You can try to use State Management like Provider, GetX, or BLoC

Comment: @SeptianDika I used provider but the same thing happens and I don't think for just two widget using setState is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really interesting question. The problem was syncing both the scrollviews. I made few changes to your code to achieve the desired result.

The basic idea is to remove listener to the other scroll before forcing pixels. After the scroll, add the same listener. <strike>But because it happens instantaneously and actual scroll happens sometimes in future, they don't overlap perfectly.</strike>

So I had to introduce `CancelableCompleter` from the async library to make sure add operation does not happen if another scroll event had happened.

With `forcePixels`, the scrolling to other wheel is not deferred hence CancelableCompleter is not required.

```dart
// ignore_for_file: invalid_use_of_protected_member

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'List',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const List(),
    );
  }
}

class List extends StatefulWidget {
  const List({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ListState createState() => _ListState();
}

class _ListState extends State<List> {
  final _firstScrollController = FixedExtentScrollController();
  final _secondScrollController = FixedExtentScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firstScrollController.addListener(_firstScrollListener);
    _secondScrollController.addListener(_secondScrollListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _firstScrollController
      ..removeListener(_firstScrollListener)
      ..dispose();
    _secondScrollController
      ..removeListener(_secondScrollListener)
      ..dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _firstScrollListener() {
    _secondScrollController.removeListener(_secondScrollListener);
    _secondScrollController.position.forcePixels(_firstScrollController.offset);
    _secondScrollController.addListener(_secondScrollListener);
  }

  void _secondScrollListener() {
    _firstScrollController.removeListener(_firstScrollListener);
    _firstScrollController.position.forcePixels(_secondScrollController.offset);
    _firstScrollController.addListener(_firstScrollListener);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("List"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 600,
              width: 300,
              child: ListWheelScrollView(
                  itemExtent: 100,
                  controller: _firstScrollController,
                  physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                  onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {
                    print('first wheel : item selected: $value');
                  },
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) ...[
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                      )
                    ]
                  ]),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 600,
              width: 300,
              child: ListWheelScrollView(
                  controller: _secondScrollController,
                  physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                  itemExtent: 100,
                  onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {
                    print('second wheel : item selected: $value');
                  },
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) ...[
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                      )
                    ]
                  ]),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

I am using protective member function `forcePixels` as Flutter has not provided any way to set pixels without animation without creating subclass of ScrollPosition. If you are fine with this linter warning, it is all good. If not, we will have to extend ListWheelScrollView to use ScrollPosition where we could make changes as per need.

Comment: @Ramji made few changes.

Comment: fun fact: You are using BlueStacks for development and I work there.

Comment: using forcePixels impact the performance ? Could you add on to how the code works ? I like Bluestack I have been using Bluestack since I was a kid because I could not afford a phone.

Comment: Removed CancelableCompleter as it is not required. The code is much simpler. I have edited explanation as well.

Comment: Is there a way to toggle on and off the concurrency of the list that is, it could scroll individually and synchronously according to some conditions.

Comment: You can remove listeners or change to different listeners and change them back to provided listeners based on your conditions

Answer (score 1):

Try separate two `controller` and add listener like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'List',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const List(),
    );
  }
}

class List extends StatefulWidget {
  const List({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListState createState() => _ListState();
}

class _ListState extends State<List> {
  final scrollController1 = FixedExtentScrollController();
  final scrollController2 = FixedExtentScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController1.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController1.position.hasPixels) {
        scrollController2.animateTo(
          scrollController1.offset,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 10), //adjust delay you need
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("List"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 600,
              width: 150,
              child: ListWheelScrollView(
                  itemExtent: 100,
                  controller: scrollController1,
                  physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) ...[
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                      )
                    ]
                  ]),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 600,
              width: 150,
              child: ListWheelScrollView(
                  controller: scrollController2,
                  physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                  itemExtent: 100,
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) ...[
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                      )
                    ]
                  ]),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: The list still lags

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late ScrollController _controllerA;
  late ScrollController _controllerB;
  ///   FixedExtentScrollController
  /// late FixedExtentScrollController _controllerA;
  /// late FixedExtentScrollController _controllerB;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controllerA = ScrollController();
    _controllerB = ScrollController();
    /// _controllerA = FixedExtentScrollController();
    /// _controllerB = FixedExtentScrollController();
    _controllerA.addListener(() {
      if (_controllerA.position.hasPixels) {
        _controllerB.jumpTo(_controllerA.offset);
      }
    });
    /// if you neet bind _controllerB to _controllerA

    /// _controllerB.addListener(() {
    ///  if (_controllerB.position.hasPixels) {
    ///    _controllerA.jumpTo(_controllerB.offset);
    ///  }
    ///});
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerA.dispose();
    _controllerB.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget _listView(Color color, ScrollController controller) {
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2;
    return Container(
      width: width,
      child: ListView.builder(
          controller: controller,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 100,
          itemExtent: 50,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: color, border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
            );
          }),
    );
  }

  /// ListWheelScrollView 
  /// Widget _listView(Color color, FixedExtentScrollController controller) {
  ///   var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2;
  ///   return Container(
  ///     width: width,
  ///     child: ListWheelScrollView(
  ///         physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
  ///         controller: controller,
  ///         itemExtent: 50,
  ///         children: [
  ///           ...List.generate(
  ///               100,
  ///               (index) => Container(
  ///                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
  ///                         color: color,
  ///                         border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
  ///                   ))
  ///         ]),
  ///   );
  /// }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Row(
        children: [
          _listView(Colors.red, _controllerA),
          _listView(Colors.yellow, _controllerB),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This code does not work with FixedExtendScrollPhysics

Comment: No, it works fine.
I added the implementation of ListWheelScrollView, good luck~~~

Comment: It works but if I scroll gradually holding the list, it lags

Answer (score 0):

Better Approach is to use [linked_scroll_controller](https://pub.dev/packages/linked_scroll_controller).

Scrolling widgets will create a default scroll controller (ScrollController class) if none is provided. A scroll controller creates a ScrollPosition to manage the state specific to an individual Scrollable widget.

To link our scroll controllers we’ll use linked_scroll_controller, a scroll controller that allows two or more scroll views to be in sync.

```
late LinkedScrollControllerGroup _verticalControllersGroup;
late ScrollController _verticalController1;
late ScrollController _verticalController2;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _verticalControllersGroup = LinkedScrollControllerGroup();
  _verticalController1 = _verticalControllersGroup.addAndGet();
  _verticalController2 = _verticalControllersGroup.addAndGet();
}
```

Now use these controllers on your listviews.

below are two nice examples which will help you to use linked_scroll_controller in your case.

[Flutter: How to create linked scroll widgets](https://pjbelo.medium.com/flutter-how-to-create-linked-scroll-widgets-136f2dd078d4)

[Flutter: Creating a two-direction scrolling table with a fixed head and column](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/flutter-creating-a-two-direction-scrolling-table-with-fixed-head-and-column-4a34fc01378f)

[Creating a two-direction scrolling with linked_scroll_controller](https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/blob/master/packages/linked_scroll_controller/README.md)

Comment: linked_scroll_controller does not support Fixed Extended Scroll Physics and my app requires this physics.